# Spring Boot and JOOQ Auditing Solutions

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq, audit

does anybody has an idea how to do auditing with **Spring Boot** and **JOOQ** (*Java Object Oriented Queries*)?

I don't want ***custom*** audit, because I already have an idea how to do that. Does JOOQ has out of the box auditing engine like Hibernate / JPA (Envers)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe this is a simular issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534872/jooq-equivalent-of-hibernate-interceptor-for-populating-history-fields and there is also an open JOOQ issue here https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1592

Comment: I hope they will solve that quickly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, that feature is on the roadmap: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1592

It is currently not a priority because jOOQ favours SQL-based solutions, and auditing is a lot more thoroughly solved through triggers than through any client-based approach, as triggers cannot be bypassed. Hibernate Envers can easily be bypassed through Hibernate API itself, e.g. when using JPQL bulk updates, or the native SQL API. A jOOQ based solution would be the same, it can easily be bypassed (more easily than in JPA, because jOOQ encourages using SQL).

Again, this may be fine for some setups, but it certainly means it's not a priority.

Comment: Thank you Lucas for your answer.